# "The authentication type is not allowed for this method call" error in authorize.net ios sdk

Tags: ios

I am trying to use authorize ios sdk as payment gateway in my application. I have integrated successfully, but I am getting above error with the test account.

```
AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

[an setDelegate:self];

CreditCardType *creditCardType = [CreditCardType creditCardType];
creditCardType.cardNumber = @"38000000000006";
creditCardType.cardCode = @"100";
creditCardType.expirationDate = @"121213";

PaymentType *paymentType = [PaymentType paymentType];
paymentType.creditCard = creditCardType;

ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeTax = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
extendedAmountTypeTax.amount = @"0";
extendedAmountTypeTax.name = @"Tax";

ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeShipping = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
extendedAmountTypeShipping.amount = @"0";
extendedAmountTypeShipping.name = @"Shipping";

LineItemType *lineItem = [LineItemType lineItem];
lineItem.itemName = @"Soda";
lineItem.itemDescription = @"Soda";
lineItem.itemQuantity = @"1";
lineItem.itemPrice = @"1.00";
lineItem.itemID = @"1";

TransactionRequestType *requestType = [TransactionRequestType transactionRequest];
requestType.lineItems = [NSArray arrayWithObject:lineItem];
requestType.amount = @"1.00";
requestType.payment = paymentType;
requestType.tax = extendedAmountTypeTax;
requestType.shipping = extendedAmountTypeShipping;

CreateTransactionRequest *request = [CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest];
request.transactionRequest = requestType;
request.transactionType = AUTH_ONLY;
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
[[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.sessionToken = sessionToken;
//[an authorizeWithRequest:request];
[an purchaseWithRequest:request];
```

Comment: Did you get the answer to this? I also am having the same issue

Comment: Maybe it will help someone later, but I got this error because I accidentally used null as value for merchant ID and transaction key.

Answer (score 5):

If your device is already registered then
comment the device registration code
Below line is for registration, please comment it

```
[an mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest:mobileDeviceRegistrationRequest];
```

Hope this is helpful for you.If any other issue please tell me.

Answer (score 2):

this error is coming because the deviceLoginRequest call is getting executed before getting response of deviceRegistrtationRequest. To avoid this error make sure you get response for deviceRegistration call before you request for deviceLogin.